# Magento HTML issue - side bar appears below the content of the page

Tags: html, css, magento

I have a webpage I have added some content to, using Magento. The side bar that usually appears to the left side of the content, but is appearing beneath the content of the page (below the content that I added myself using html)

See image for reference:
 [image: the blue box shows the side bar, which should appear at the top of the page to the left side of the content]

With my limited knowledge I cannot find a solution, I have searched various forms, and attempted it myself, with no success. I tried making the max width of the body 800px for example, and that just made my entire page go to 800px wide.
Does anyone have any idea on what im doing wrong? If you need to see the code or anything I can add it?

Any help is appreciated.

*Update - additional photos*

[image: code I created]

[image: view of the page I added the code too]

Comment: Just because there is no CSS on the page does not mean there is no CSS involved. Looking at the screenshot there is definitely CSS there. Please share some code or else it is not possible for folks to help.

Comment: Hi @Simran sure no problem:

Comment: I have attached two images, one showing all the code I added, in the description box. The second is just a view of the the layout of the page I work on. 
I added the images to the main question above. I hope it helps..

Comment: Please don't use images to display code. Paste them in pastebin.

Comment: Not to sound dumb...too late... where or what is pastebin?

Answer (score 0):

Check the ierarchy inside the xml file containing those blocks and also the .phtml template which is calling those blocks.
You might also have an unclosed HTML tag in your DOM or another typo.

Comment: Thanks for that @Alexandru I will check the xml and phtml and review the tags to make sure all are closed